# Firefox reinstalls and enables synchronized addons that I have removed

Tags: firefox, linux-mint, firefox-extensions, firefox-profile, firefox-sync

I want to remove some themes while keeping addons synchronized, because I don't want to have to reinstall them all (the ones I want to keep).

But after I remove these themes that I don't want anymore, I think the synchronization system brings them back because they appear installed after logging back to the system or even after a while.

Even more, when synchronization brings them back, one of the themes is set as enabled - when in fact I had  it disabled... before removing it!

[image]

Is synchronization supposed to act this way? Shouldn't it detect and synchronize ***removal*** just as much as ***installation*** of addons?

Can this behavior be adjusted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug but I have found a workaround.

- Uncheck the synchronization of addons.
- Remove the unwanted addons (here, themes)
- Restart Firefox
- Re-anable addons synchronization (I did this in fact only after a few days)

Answer (score 0):

If cirpricus' answer doesn't solve it for you, there's an alternative route to reset your sync data:

To delete all of the data associated with your Firefox sync account:

- Go to Firefox Accounts
- Login using the information associated with your sync account
- Delete your account
- Signup for a new sync account using the Firefox Accounts website or
  directly from Firefox

Source: Wesley Branton @ https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1037353